# TinyMCE 5 : Image is not showing unless there is a text after the image

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

If we add an image through the insert image option in TinyMCE editor. Preview is showing up properly. But after submit the image disappears.

If you add a text or a dot(.) followed the image it works.

```
tinymce.init({
      selector: 'textarea#myTxtID',
      height: 335,
        resize: "both",
      plugins: [
                'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
                'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
                'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
                'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools'
        ],
        toolbar1: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
        toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons'
    });
```

It didnt work when only there is an image.

[image]

but it works when there is an extra text

[image]

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find a solution and temporarily fixed it by adding an invisible dot(.)

```
tinyMCE.get('myTxtID').getContent()+'<p style=\"display:none\">.</p>'
```